# Fifo opening issue C

Tags: c, fifo

I have this code:

```
mkfifo ("bPipe", 0660); /* Create named pipe */


int fd1 = open ("bPipe", O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK); /* Open named pipe for writing */

perror("FD1");

int fd = open ("bPipe", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK); /* Open it for reading */

 perror("FD");

char*mex="Hello world\n\0";

write (fd1,mex , getStringLenght(mex)+1); 

char* result = readline(fd1);

printf("Rc %s : \n",result);
```

I'm studying the FIFO in C and I tried to create two FIFO but after opening them I get this two errors:

```
FD1:Device not configured
FD:Device not configured
```

and I dont understand why.

P.S "readLine" and "getStringLenght" are my functions

Comment: please share more code - what's is "bPipe"?  something like this one ? mknod(FIFO_FILE, S_IFIFO|0666, 0);

Comment: "bPipe" is fifo's name

Answer (score 6):

Documentation of [`fifo(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) states:

> A process can open a FIFO in nonblocking mode.  In this case, opening
>          for read-only will succeed even if no-one has opened on the write
>          side yet, opening for write-only will fail with ENXIO (no such device
>          or address) unless the other end has already been opened.

That's exactly what you do. You open the pipe for write first but there's not a read end opened yet. If you swap the read/write calls to `open()` you should be fine.

I believe you are actually checking the return codes of open() before calling perror(). In all cases, you should set `errno` to `0` before calling a library function (include `<errno.h>`) as `errno` might be set to some other value by the some other library/system call.

Comment: sorry I get a strange thing: I opened the first read and then write and now it works, but if I open first write and then read it isn't work. Why?

Comment: @mariorazzu Why are you using `O_NONBLOCK`?

Comment: why its the same process and if I dont set O_NONBLOCK flag the program block on open function

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I really don't see anything, that tells me there's an error here somewhere. As for the printed messages you get, you see, first you have to figure if an error is **really** there. For that you have to check return values of `open()`. And only if return values indicate error, then `perror()` makes sense.